# django makemigrations and migrate on heroku server don't create tables

Tags: python, django, database, heroku

Python Version 2.7
Django Version 1.9.7

I have created a Django app on heroku.  I can't get the heroku server to `migrate` properly.  In the past I have done all the `makemigrations` locally and then pushed them to the server.  It has worked in the past.  Now I thought I would choose to do the migrations all on the server side, since I am not running this app locally at all.

I just created one new model inside the `models.py` for app 'main':

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class InstagramPhotos(models.Model):
    imageId = models.IntegerField()
    userId = models.IntegerField()
    likes = models.IntegerField()
    captionText = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField()
```

After pushing changes to the server, I ran this, with following output:

```
heroku run python manage.py makemigrations main
```

> Running python manage.py makemigrations main on ⬢
>   glacial-beach-50253... up, run.8354 Migrations for 'main':
>   **0001_initial.py:
>       - Create model InstagramPhotos**

Seems ok right?  So then I try to `migrate` which as you know will actually create the tables in the DB:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

> Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ glacial-beach-50253... up,
>   run.7556 Operations to perform:   Apply all migrations: auth,
>   contenttypes, admin, sessions Running migrations:   **No migrations to
>   apply.**   Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a
>   migration, and so won't be applied.   Run 'manage.py makemigrations'
>   to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply
>   them.

No matter how many times I have tried to re-run the `makemigrations` and then `migrate` it still seems to not pick it up.  Not sure why this is happening besides it is just not possible to operate on heroku server this way?  Do I definitely need to do `makemigrations` locally and push?

FYI I just have the default sqlite3 DB still defined in `settings.py`.

Comment: **Don't run makemigrations on Heroku**. Do it locally, commit the result and push, and then run migrate on Heroku.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't been able to do that yet, since it would like me makemigrations locally without getting all my dependencies up-to-date.  I guess with the new version of Django they require Pillow, didn't have that yet thought I would try to do all this on the server which installed the dependencies of course no problem.  I see now that isn't in the cards.

Comment: How can you do any development at all if you can run the application locally?

Comment: Yes I solved the dependency issues.  Its not that I really couldn't, but that I didn't do it yet.  From my point of view it seems reasonable that I could run the migrations on the server.  Not sure why it doesn't work still, but OK.  Reason I don't run it on the local server is that I am working with a 3rd party API which redirects to a public URL for authentication, so that wouldn't really work from my local machine.  But anyway thank you I just did the makemigrations locally and pushed them.  The migrations then worked on the server. @DanielRoseman

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65739543/migrations-are-not-taking-place-after-pushing-my-code-on-heroku can you ans quite similar problem ?

Comment: The correct migration flow is: make migrations + migrate locally, then push/deploy migrations to Heroku. Heroku might migrate automatically during the deploy (depends on the Procfile you maintain), but if not, you can try migrating manually, as you already tried. However, this is the 'happy path', which might end up badly from several possible reasons. In such cases, try to revert your changes, locally, repeat the migration procedure (include deploy), then commit again your changes and repeat once again the migration flow. That will put you back on the 'happy-path' in most cases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How heroku run python manage.py migrate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40790533/how-heroku-run-python-manage-py-migrate)

Answer (score 28):

I had a similar problem.

I just `ssh` into heroku dyno with:
`heroku run bash` ( from your heroku application folder ofc )

Than run all the migration and makemigration commands with createsuperuser if needed.
Works with sqlite and postgre for me.

Comment: Yeah after the time since the post I have learned much better how to use heroku.  You never need to `makemigrations` on the heroku server.  You should always `makemigrations` locally then push then to the server.  you should only have to `migrate` on the server.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't realized that heroku commands persisted through each dyno

Comment: @Dishant Chavra https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65739543/migrations-are-not-taking-place-after-pushing-my-code-on-heroku can you ans quite similar problem ?

Comment: Hi, I'm having a similar problem, but I'm unable to run makemigrations locally, because I use heroku postgres database and it says "User does not have CONNECT privilege." any ideas on what could help?

Comment: that usually means you didn't specify database name.

Comment: works for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. Run these commands locally:

```bash
python manage.py makemigrations 
python manage.py migrate
```

2. Commit your code
3. Push it to Heroku master
4. Run

```bash
heroku run python manage.py makemigrations 
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

Your issue should be resolved now.

Comment: What do these `,,,,` mean?

Comment: oops!. ignore them please

Answer (score 1):

I struggled recently with a similar error and ended discovering that i mistakenly have been git ignoring **init**.py files. Without these files in the migrations folder, the migrate command cannot find the migration files and execute them.

Answer (score 1):

Run `makemigrations` and `migrate`, then pushed to remote repo.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error two times while deploying to Heroku. While listing the files under the app directory, I found out **db.sqlite3** file was missing which is necessary for django to create the sql tables. While it automatically creates the file in local, it wasn't getting created on the heroku while running migrate command.

There are two options from here:

1. create db.sqlite3 file on heroku under your app directory
2. run "python manage.py migrate" locally to create the db.sqlite3 and push it to the
   heroku repo