# How heroku run python manage.py migrate?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I deployed a simple Django app in Heroku

Steps:

```
- git push heroku master

- heroku run python manage.py makemigrations ( or + app_name)
```

it seem to affect:

```
  0002_main.py:
- Create model Comment
- Remove field status from match
- Remove field quantity from slot
- Add field avatar to account
- Add field slots to match
- Alter field verification_code on account
- Alter field verification_code on slot
- Add field match_object to comment
- Add field user to comment
- Alter index_together for comment (1 constraint(s))
```

then I run

```
- heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

but i received:

```
  Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your migration files should be committed to your source control, and never run `makemigrations` on heroku.

With committed migration files, this problem becomes non existant.

Comment: that right, I missed the migration files, I just ran makemigrations on heroku

Comment: But what if we wanted to do so. e.g, if we have altered a model of an app which is from an installed package and we want to show that on the server, as we don't send the packages but just a requirements.txt file

Answer (score 20):

Make sure you have committed migrations file.
then run

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

You can specify the app name in the following way:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate -a <app-name>
```

Please see this documentation.

Answer (score 3):

The Heroku filesystem is read-only as per the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).

This means that when you disconnect from the dyno the files created by the  `makemigrations` command will be destroyed.

To solve your issue you can:

1. Commit your migration files to Github(or your source control system) and then run the `migrate` command on the Heroku shell - *recommended*
2. Create the migration files and then run the migration on the [heroku bash shell](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#an-example-one-off-dyno). - *NOT RECOMMENDED on production*

Answer (score 3):

To make Heroku handle applying the migrations when deploying add the following to you Procfile

`release: python manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 1):

Either

`heroku run python manage.py migrate`

or

`heroku run python3 manage.py migrate`

If needed to specify app name:

`heroku run python3 manage.py migrate -a <app-name>`

Comment: hm good one, trying to run python manage.py migrate from the ssh connection (directly on the VM) results in 5432 port error, thanks