# Heroku - When I run 'heroku run python manage.py migrate' I get an error

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku

When I try to migrate my project to heroku by running the above error, I get the following:

```
C:\Users\{MyUser}\Desktop\My Site\mysite>heroku run python manage.py migrate
Running python manage.py migrate on ? {project name}... !
 !    Cannot run one-off process at this time. Please try again later.

C:\Users\{MyUser}\Desktop\My Site\mysite>heroku run python manage.py makemigrations
Running python manage.py makemigrations on ? {project name}... !
 !    Cannot run one-off process at this time. Please try again later.
```

I have tried 'makemigrations' as well.

Is this an error? On my end or Heroku's?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40793541/1577947

Comment: Did you get this resolved? If so, how? I'm hitting the same issue. I tried the tips at the above link but it made no difference.