# ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'django' when trying to run makemigrations

Tags: python, django

I have taken over maintenance of a deployed Django app that is used by employees. I have made minor changes here and there and I only had to restart the apache to implement the changes. For the first time, I have to add an integerfield model to one of the pre-existing models. This said value is already in the DB with default value of 0 for all rows. All I want to do is add it as one of the fields in one of the models but when I try to run

```
sudo python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

in the virtual environment, I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback(most recent call last):
    File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
     ) from exc
```

As the app is currently running fine, why am I receiving this error?
If this is not how you apply changes in the model field in the live server, how else are you supposed to do it?

Thank you so much!

edit:
List list of pip installed packages:

```
APScheduler==3.5.3
astroid==1.6.4
Django==2.0.5
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
freezegun==0.3.10
holidays==0.9.6
isort==4.3.4
jdcal==1.4
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
mccabe==0.6.1
mock==2.0.0
mod-wsgi==4.6.4
mysqlclient==1.3.12
openpyxl==2.5.3
pandas==0.24.2
pbr==4.2.0
pylint==1.9.1
pylint-django==0.11.1
pylint-plugin-utils==0.2.6
python-dateutil==2.7.3
pytz==2018.4
rope==0.10.7
simplejson==3.16.0
six==1.11.0
tzlocal==1.5.1
wrapt==1.10.11
```

Comment: First make sure that your virtual environment is activated. Then try running it without `sudo` command. When running it with `sudo`, it is probably using administrators python environment not your virtual environment.

Comment: Is Django installed? Or do you need to activate the correct virtual environment that has Django installed? Run `pip freeze | grep Django` to verify it is installed.

Comment: Thank yall for the quick reply! Yes Django is installed and without sudo,it says I don't have permission to run manage.py

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use `python` instead of `python3`? I'm wondering if Python2 has it installed but Python3 does not.

Comment: @ScottSkiles This was my initial thought, but you'd receive a `SyntaxError` if you try to run `python2 manage.py` on a project made for python3, So OP wouldn't be getting `ModuleNotFoundError` if that were the case.

Comment: Yeah, `python2` is not a thing. I was thinking just `python`. That defaults to python 2. Can you tell us more about your virtual env? Which env provider are you using? `virtualenv`? `conda`? Something else?

Comment: @ScottSkiles `python2` **is** a thing.

Comment: I would suggest running:

    pipenv --rm && pipenv install --python=<path to python> && pipenv shell

Then try to run your python manage.py again.

Comment: Please, can you post the output of `pip freeze`? Also, provide which version of `Python` are you using? Are you using a `virtual environment` or not?

Comment: @CalebGoodman the more you know! thx

Comment: Considering the server is live and already running, would running pipenv --rm && pipenv install --python=<path to python> && pipenv shell be ok? And my python version is 3.6.5, I am using the virutal environment and the I have added my pip list in the main post.

Comment: @JohnGear Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38330432/django-makemigrations-and-migrate-on-heroku-server-dont-create-tables).  This doesn't answer your question, but it suggests that you should *always* run `makemigrations` locally, push the update to your server, **then** run migrate on the live server.