# Heroku doesn't migrate models in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, django-models, django-migrations

I have a Django app deployed on Heroku.
I am trying to switch the database from mySQL to Postgres using the Heroku Postgres addon

I erased all migrations and ran manage.py makemigrations to get a clean migration log.
Then I commit and push.

If I run manage.py migrate on my local machine, this is what I get:
Migrations for 'manager':

```
  manager/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model AbiMapping
    - Create model MissingContracts
    - Create model TempEmailAccounts
    - Create model UnsupportedMetaContracts
    - Create model Users
    - Create model Passwords
    - Create model ContractMapping
    - Create model Tokens
```

I added this command to Procfile so migrate runs when I push to Heroku:

```
release: python3 manage.py migrate
```

When pushing to Heroku, the migrate call works but it doesn't migrate the models I have in the app:

```
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
remote: Running release command...
remote: 
remote: Operations to perform:
remote:   Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, manager, sessions
remote: Running migrations:
remote:   No migrations to apply.
```

This is how I setup the database is settings.py:

.env sets environment variables on local machine. On heroku database environment variables are loaded from environment as there is not .env

```
dotenv_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env")
if os.path.isfile(dotenv_file):
    dotenv.load_dotenv(dotenv_file)
```

Setup database:

```
DATABASES = {}
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)

django_on_heroku.settings(locals())
```

it seems like the database does exist in heroku:

```
$ heroku config
=== frame-zero Config Vars
DATABASE_URL: postgres://<details of my database address and credentials>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38330432/django-makemigrations-and-migrate-on-heroku-server-dont-create-tables). the trick is to run the bash on Heroku Dyno first. first run `Heroku run bash` then inside the bash window run `Python manage.py makemigrations` and after that `Python manage.py migrate`.