# psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "django_content_type" does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, django, heroku

I'm trying for the first time to deploy my Django project to heroku, but I'm running in some issues, when trying to:

- Register/Login
- heroku run python manage.py makemigrations
- heroku run python manage.py migrate (also with --fake)

This error shows up:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "django_content_type" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_co...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 268, in handle
    emit_post_migrate_signal(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 42, in emit_post_migrate_signal
    models.signals.post_migrate.send(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 180, in send
    return [
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 181, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 42, in create_permissions
    create_contenttypes(app_config, verbosity=verbosity, interactive=interactive, using=using, apps=apps, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/management/__init__.py", line 119, in create_contenttypes
    content_types, app_models = get_contenttypes_and_models(app_config, using, ContentType)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/management/__init__.py", line 94, in get_contenttypes_and_models
    content_types = {
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 280, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_co...
```

Before I was using the default db.sqlite3 database

settings.py

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_elasticsearch_dsl',
    'psycopg2',
    'malbucket'
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgres',
    }
}
DATABASES["default"] = dj_database_url.config(default=urllib.parse.quote(os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL", "").encode("utf-8")))
```

manage.py dbshell

```
                  List of relations
 Schema |       Name        | Type  |     Owner      
--------+-------------------+-------+----------------
 public | django_migrations | table | <name>
 public | django_session    | table | <name>
```

Thank you.

heroku run python manage.py showmigrations

```
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
 [X] 0010_alter_group_name_max_length
 [X] 0011_update_proxy_permissions
 [X] 0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
```

Comment: Can you share the output of `manage.py showmigrations`? If you ran `manage.py migrate --fake` then you may have marked some migrations as applied without running them

Comment: Yeah, looks like you have faked all your migrations and not run them. Deleting the DB and running your migrations on a blank DB is probably easiest

Comment: @IainShelvington actually OP isn't considering that in heroku pods the files are _ephemeral_. They are creating the migration files using `heroku run python manage.py makemigrations` but when they run the next command `heroku run python manage.py migrate` the migrate command is probably running in a new container so no migration files exist. You should **commit** your migrations to source control, you'll end up in a pickle later if you follow this kind of workflow for migrations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django makemigrations and migrate on heroku server don't create tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38330432/django-makemigrations-and-migrate-on-heroku-server-dont-create-tables)

Comment: Thank you, solved by following the correct workflow.